# Como receber um valor do usuário para ser calculado em uma função usando Sympy?

Tags: python

Estou usando a Biblioteca Sympy do Python, porem, não achei uma forma de calcular o resultado de uma função usando ela, ou seja, tenho a minha função que vai ser digitada pelo usuário, e o valor de x que também vai ser digitada por ele. ex: função = x + 10 e meu valor de x = 2. quero o retorno de 12, porem é isso que não achei como fazer em sua documentação. Minha Tentativa:

```
from sympy import *

E = input("função ?  ")
x = int(input("Digite o valor de x "))
SimboloX = ('x')
R = solve(function(E,x),SimboloX)
print(R)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr`:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

expr = input('Qual é a expressão em x? ')
x = int(input('E qual é o valor de x? '))

expression = parse_expr(expr)
result = expression.subs('x', x)

print(f'O resultado de {expr} para x={x} é {result}')
```

Saída de exemplo:

```
> Qual é a expressão em x? x + 2
> E qual é o valor de x? 10
O resultado de x + 2 para x=10 é 12
```